# Rmarkdown html whitespace

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am trying to add space between two tables and three graphs on an rmarkdown file that is knit into html. I was able to add space between two tables and add a header to the second table as follows

````
end of first table code
```

\  

### Header For Second Table
````

However when I go to use either another header between tables or add whitespace similarly to above, the header shows up on the side of the table [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKZy7.png) and no whitespace is added.

I am using pixiedust to make the tables and ggplot2 to make the graphs.

Comment: Did you try `<br>` as breaks?

Comment: If you want spaces between tables, try using margins. Hard coding spaces obviously doesn't work well.

Comment: @timfaber `<br>` did not work

Comment: I'm not sure what your aim is, can you either provide a reproducible example or some desired output image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the following around your first table:

````
### First Table
<div style="margin-bottom:100px;">
```{r}
# RCODE
```
</div>
````

Swapping the lines of your table header and the `<div....` makes no big difference.