# R Markdown add White Space to HTML Output

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I've found several suggestions for adding whitespace to R Markdown documents including `<br>`, `\newpage` and some other things.

These don't work for my HTML output, maybe there's a better way. I'd like to do two things in the example below:

(1) Add extra whitespace between the title and the first header

(2) Add extra whitespace between the first and second paragraphs

Let's go with the default R Markdown document shown below. How would I accomplish this extra white space for HTML output?

````
---
title: "Here is the title"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

FIRST PARAGRAPH This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

SECOND PARAGRAPH you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`div`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) elements to divide sections within your [R Markdown file](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_intro.html). Inside each `div` tag, assign each [`margin-bottom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-bottom) property a margin value. Values closer to 100% increase the amount of white space.

Thank you for @Martin Schmelzer answer to the SO post [Rmarkdown html whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285167/rmarkdown-html-whitespace).

[image: SS of HTML Output]

````
---
title: "Here is the title"
output: html_document
---
<div style="margin-bottom:100px;">
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
</div>
## R Markdown
<div style="margin-bottom:50px;">
</div>
FIRST PARAGRAPH This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

SECOND PARAGRAPH you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
````

Answer (score 16):

A simple solution to add a line of white space is to use $~$

This adds a line of white space and has worked reliably for me with html output.

```
# R Markdown

Some text

$~$

More text after a white space
```

Comment: Please try adding a line break before and after the $~$.  Note: edited above to reflect this.

Comment: adding a line break before and after didn't change anything

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you.  Here's another reference to this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543454/create-two-blank-lines-in-markdown

Comment: nice!  Even works today in Word as well as HTML...   if I switch to Word, still produces whitespace and not those characters :)

Answer (score 13):

Since the question is about styling an `html_document`, you have to use some `CSS` rules. There are many means to obtain the desired formatting.

In order to find a set of `CSS` rules that achieve your goal, it is necessary to inspect the rendered `HTML` document. Here's the relevant `HTML` fragment of the default `R Markdown` document provided in the question:

```
<div class="fluid-row" id="header">
  <h1 class="title toc-ignore">Here is the title</h1>
</div>

<div id="r-markdown" class="section level2">
  <h2>R Markdown</h2>
  <p>FIRST PARAGRAPH This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <a href="http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com" class="uri">http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com</a>.</p>
  <p>SECOND PARAGRAPH you click the <strong>Knit</strong> button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:</p>
</div>
```

Here is one solution that uses the [`margin` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) and the [`:first-of-type` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type):

````
---
title: "Here is the title"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{css echo=FALSE}
/* Define a margin before h2 element */
h2  {
  margin-top: 6em;
}

/* Define a margin after every first p elements */
p:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
``` 

## R Markdown

FIRST PARAGRAPH This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

SECOND PARAGRAPH you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
````

If you use these `CSS` rules in your final document, you may be disappointed because you'll get a space before each `h2` element and after each first `p` element. So, you may prefer selecting elements with the `div` identifier:

````
```{css echo=FALSE}
#r-markdown  {
  margin-top: 6em;
}

#r-markdown p:first-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
```
````